# Ring of Endomorphism over $\mathbb{Z}_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I must have some definition problem which I can't put my finger on:
When defining homomorphism of rings $ f :R \mapsto S$, we require:
$f(1_R)=1_s$
$f(r_1+r_2)=f(r_1)+f(r_2)$
Now I have question asks to prove that End($\mathbb{Z}_n$) isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$. If every endomorphism $f$ must send 1 to itself, and preserve sum, how can I get 2 different enomorphisms?

Comment: Most likely $\operatorname{End}(\mathbb Z_n)$ is used here to denote the endomorphisms of $\mathbb Z_n$ as a $\mathbb Z$-module (abelian group). Hence, you only require $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$.

Comment: Now that makes sense :) thx alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment:

The notation $\operatorname{End}(\mathbb Z_n)$ is used here to denote the endomorphisms of $\mathbb Z_n$ as a $\mathbb Z$-module (abelian group). Hence, $f\colon \mathbb Z_n\to\mathbb Z_n$ is in $\operatorname{End}(\mathbb Z_n)$ iff $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$.

Those $\mathbb Z$-module endomorphisms form a ring with addition defined point-wise by $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+ g(x)$ and multiplication given by composition as $(f\circ g)(x)=f(g(x))$.

You can show that every such $f$ will come in the form $f_k(x)=kx$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z_n$ and then see that $f_k + f_l = f_{k+l}$ and $f_k \circ f_l = f_{k\cdot l}$, which turns $k \mapsto f_k$ into (bijective) a ring homomorphism $\mathbb Z_n\to \operatorname{End}(\mathbb Z_n)$, since also $1\mapsto \operatorname{id}_{\mathbb Z_n}$, which is the one-element in $\operatorname{End}(\mathbb Z_n)$.